# How to get the start date and end date of each week in a month using Python?

Tags: python

Desired Output for the month of feb 2023

```
{
  "week_1": { "start_date": "2023-01-30", "end_date": "2023-02-04" },
  "week_2": { "start_date": "2023-02-06", "end_date": "2023-02-11" },
  "week_3": { "start_date": "2023-02-13", "end_date": "2023-02-18" },
  "week_4": { "start_date": "2023-02-20", "end_date": "2023-02-25" },
  "week_5": { "start_date": "2023-02-27", "end_date": "2023-03-04" }
}
```

what i have done so far
i want the output as if the monday start from the previous month then take prev month monday as start day for the week and end date as the current month date. the date should be from monday to saturday.

```
import datetime
import json


def get_weeks(year, month):
    # get the first day of the month
    first_day = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
    
    # get the date of the previous Monday
    prev_monday = first_day - datetime.timedelta(days=first_day.weekday())

    # get the date of the first Saturday
    first_saturday = prev_monday + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
    weeks = {}
    start_date = prev_monday
    for i in range(1, 6):
        # get the end date for the current week
        end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
        # check if the end date is in the next month
        if end_date.month != month:
            # merge the current week with the next week
            next_monday = end_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            next_week = {
                "start_date": next_monday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                "end_date": (next_monday + datetime.timedelta(days=6)).strftime(
                    "%Y-%m-%d"
                ),
            }
            weeks[f"week_{i}"] = {
                "start_date": start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                "end_date": end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            }
            weeks[f"week_{i+1}"] = next_week
            start_date = next_monday + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        else:
            # add the current week to the dictionary
            weeks[f"week_{i}"] = {
                "start_date": start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                "end_date": end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            }
            start_date = end_date + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    return weeks


week_dates = get_weeks(2023, 1)
print(json.dumps(week_dates, indent=4))
```

Current Code Output:

```
{
    "week_1": {
        "start_date": "2023-01-30",
        "end_date": "2023-02-04"
    },
    "week_2": {
        "start_date": "2023-02-06",
        "end_date": "2023-02-11"
    },
    "week_3": {
        "start_date": "2023-02-13",
        "end_date": "2023-02-18"
    },
    "week_4": {
        "start_date": "2023-02-20",
        "end_date": "2023-02-25"
    },
    "week_5": {
        "start_date": "2023-02-27",
        "end_date": "2023-03-04"
    },
    "week_6": {
        "start_date": "2023-03-05",
        "end_date": "2023-03-11"
    }
}
```

my current code is giving an another week for the next month i want to prevent this from generating another week

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? What are you asking?

Comment: you can see my current code output as it is giving another week of next month also the current code output is for the month of feb but if you get the weeks for jan it also gives another week

Answer (score 1):

The code generated an additional week for the next month because the logic in the original implementation assumed that there would always be 5 weeks in a month but, some months have 4 weeks, and some months have 6 weeks.

In the original, the loop that generates the weeks always runs 5 times, and it generates a 6th week if the end date of the 5th week is in the next month. So, for months that only have 4 weeks, the code will still generate a 5th week, and for months that have 6 weeks, the code will only generate the first 5 weeks.

To fix this issue, you can modify the code to check if the end date of the current week is in the next month, and if it is, exit the loop and return the result without generating any extra weeks. This ensures that the code generates the right number of weeks for any month.

**In this updated version of get_weeks(), we check if the end date of the current week is in the next month using end_date.month != month. If it is, we add the current week to the dictionary and exit the loop using return weeks:**

```
def get_weeks(year, month):
    # get the first day of the month
    first_day = datetime.date(year, month, 1)
    
    # get the date of the previous Monday
    prev_monday = first_day - datetime.timedelta(days=first_day.weekday())

    # get the date of the first Saturday
    first_saturday = prev_monday + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
    weeks = {}
    start_date = prev_monday
    for i in range(1, 6):
        # get the end date for the current week
        end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
        # check if the end date is in the next month
        if end_date.month != month:
            # exit the loop and return the result
            weeks[f"week_{i}"] = {
                "start_date": start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
                "end_date": end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            }
            return weeks
        # add the current week to the dictionary
        weeks[f"week_{i}"] = {
            "start_date": start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            "end_date": end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        }
        start_date = end_date + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    return weeks
```

Comment: This implementation (and the original) both fail if the month starts on Sunday or Monday. The previous week that it creates before the start of the for loop will be entirely in the previous month.  As a result it will then enter the branch for `end_date.month != month`, and in this implementation, quit immediately.  In the OP implementation, week 1 would be from the previous month, the actual first week of the month would be skipped (technically overwritten) and the week 2 would start on  the 8th.    Try `year=2023`, `month=1` as an example

Comment: Correction to my comment (which I can't edit anymore).  Only months starting on Sunday are a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the original code:

1. The code assumes every month has 5 weeks.
2. The special branch for end_date.month != month is blindly adding an additional week (this is the issue you were originally asking about)
3. If the target month starts on a Sunday (weekday = 6), then week_1 will  be entirely in the previous month. And then because of issue 2, this causes the actual first week to be stored as week 2 and then get overwritten by the following week. For example, January 2023 give the following output:)

```
{
    "week_1": {"start_date": "2022-12-26","end_date": "2022-12-31"}, # All December
    "week_2": {"start_date": "2023-01-08","end_date": "2023-01-13"}, # Week 01-02 to 01-06 is missing
    "week_3": {"start_date": "2023-01-15","end_date": "2023-01-20"},
    "week_4": {"start_date": "2023-01-22","end_date": "2023-01-27"},
    "week_5": {"start_date": "2023-01-29","end_date": "2023-02-03"},
    "week_6": {"start_date": "2023-02-04","end_date": "2023-02-10"}  # Extra week
}
```

Here is a solution based on your original code with a few changes:

1. I get the expected end_month based on the target month, and now use that as the stopping condition for While loop checking the value of `start_date.month` instead of a For loop.
2. As a side effect of switching to a while loop, I have added a counter variable to set the week_# keys
3. When checking the first_day.weekday() value, I change the value of 6 for Sunday to a -1, and then get prev_monday from that time_delta, so if the month starts on Sunday, we just go to the next day to start.
4. There is no longer any branching code needed based on `end_date.month != month`

```py
def get_weeks(year, month):
    # get the first day of the month
    first_day = datetime.date(year, month, 1)

    # Get the next month as a stopping point.
    end_month = 1 if month == 12 else month + 1

    # get the date of the previous Monday
    # If first_day is Sunday, we want to shift forward one day.
    starting_shift = -1 if first_day.weekday() == 6 else first_day.weekday()
    prev_monday = first_day - datetime.timedelta(days=starting_shift)
    # get the date of the first Saturday
    first_saturday = prev_monday + datetime.timedelta(days=5)

    weeks = {}

    start_date = prev_monday
    counter = 1  # Use to track the week label in output
    # Use a while loop until the start_date is no longer in our target month
    while start_date.month != end_month:
        # get the end date for the current week
        end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=5)
        # check if the end date is in the next month
        weeks[f"week_{counter}"] = {
            "start_date": start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
            "end_date": end_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
        }
        start_date = end_date + datetime.timedelta(days=2)
        counter += 1

    return weeks
```